# Syntax not showing single result or possible looking at the wrong colum

Tags: mysql, workbench

I'm new to this so go easy on me. I am trying to show 1 data entry with a value = to

but I am unable to find it. IF I select all then it shows up.

```
show database; 
use test; 
show tables; 
select * from test where 'License Number' = 5286;
```

I'm getting a 0 row return BUT if I just run

```
Select * from test;
```

it shows everything.

Comment: `where 'License Number' = 5286` should be ```where `License Number` = 5286```. Otherwise you are comparing against a literal string ("Licence Number") rather than to values actually stored in that column.

Comment: `License Number` is a string, not a column name. The string is not equal to 5286.